# Getting an array of TStringList to a client-side dataset in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi

I have created an array of TStringList which represents columns pulled from a delimited file. I need to bind this to a TwwDBgrid, allowing users to potentially edit the cell data. To complicate matters, I am in a position of using Delphi version 5, and I am reading recommendations of avoiding distributing the dependent assemblies required for TClientDataSet in version 5.

What other options do I have, if any? Thanks

Comment: One option is here http://www.aidaim.com/in-memory_sql_database_delphi.htm

Comment: I'd use an in-memory table attached to the DBGrid rather than an array of TStringList. If you don't want the overhead of CDS, then use something else. Maybe TkbmTable?

Comment: Can I see a part of the file?

Comment: I agree with SirRufo and DavidSchwartz's recommendation. An array of TStringList is not the way to do this. Map the columns in your delimited file to an memory dataset - KBMMemtable or Aidaim's SQLMemtable are both good and I believe KBMMemtable supports streaming delimited text in and out of the memtable if you want to persist the data after it has been edited.

Comment: I worked with large log files (50mb+) in delphi 5 and used the turbo hashed string list with StringGrid, worked well.

Comment: "Other options" with respect to what aspect of the work? You have only described one clear problem: The distribution of midas.dll. I think you need to break down and clarify your questions and problems to get the answers you are looking for. You may actually have more than one question here as well.